# Вывести список процессов на экран

Tags: c++, процесс

Как получить список процессов win ?

Попробовал такой способ:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "iostream.h"
#include "tlhelp32.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
HANDLE hSnap = NULL;
THREADENTRY32 te32;
hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0);
if (hSnap!=NULL)
{
if (Thread32First(hSnap, &te32))
{
cout << te32.th32ThreadID << " " << te32.th32OwnerProcessID << endl;
while (Thread32Next(hSnap, &te32))
cout << te32.th32ThreadID << " " << te32.th32OwnerProcessID << endl;
}
}
CloseHandle(hSnap);
return 0;
}
```

Но на экран ничего не выводит.

P.S: Только начал изучать с++, не судите =)

Comment: изучайте дальше https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms682623(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @LexHobbit, спасибо, получилось вывести но не так как хотелось, половину процессов не показывает, выводить `unknown` - https://image.prntscr.com/image/eXNv_dWoQ-aj4opGT-jaAA.png

Comment: вам прав не хватает...

Comment: @LexHobbit, Хм, Каким способом их можно дать?

Comment: честно, не помню. там как то debug flag  или привилегия назначается, гляньте это https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446619(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: вот здесь надо начинать читать https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms717797(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить `te32.dwSize = sizeof(THREADENTRY32);` после объявления `te32`

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решил: [Подробнее здесь.](http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/40504-using-ntquerysysteminformation-to-get-process-list/)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winternl.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ntdll.lib") // Need to link with ntdll.lib import library. You can find the ntdll.lib from the Windows DDK.

typedef struct _SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO
{
    ULONG                   NextEntryOffset;
    ULONG                   NumberOfThreads;
    LARGE_INTEGER           Reserved[3];
    LARGE_INTEGER           CreateTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER           UserTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER           KernelTime;
    UNICODE_STRING          ImageName;
    ULONG                   BasePriority;
    HANDLE                  ProcessId;
    HANDLE                  InheritedFromProcessId;
}SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO,*PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO;

int main()
{
    NTSTATUS status;
    PVOID buffer;
    PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO spi;

    buffer=VirtualAlloc(NULL,1024*1024,MEM_COMMIT|MEM_RESERVE,PAGE_READWRITE); // We need to allocate a large buffer because the process list can be large.

    if(!buffer)
    {
        printf("\nError: Unable to allocate memory for process list (%d)\n",GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    printf("\nProcess list allocated at address %#x\n",buffer);
    spi=(PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO)buffer;

    if(!NT_SUCCESS(status=NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation,spi,1024*1024,NULL)))
    {
        printf("\nError: Unable to query process list (%#x)\n",status);

        VirtualFree(buffer,0,MEM_RELEASE);
        return -1;
    }

    while(spi->NextEntryOffset) // Loop over the list until we reach the last entry.
    {
        printf("\nProcess name: %ws | Process ID: %d\n",spi->ImageName.Buffer,spi->ProcessId); // Display process information.
        spi=(PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO)((LPBYTE)spi+spi->NextEntryOffset); // Calculate the address of the next entry.
    }

    printf("\nPress any key to continue.\n");
    getchar();

    VirtualFree(buffer,0,MEM_RELEASE); // Free the allocated buffer.
    return 0;
}
```